# Geometry problem on circle

Tags: geometry

Let S be a circle with centre O. A chord AB, not a diameter, divides S into two regions R1 and R2 such that O belongs to R2. Let S1 be a circle with centre in R1, touching AB at X and S internally. Let S2 be a circle with centre in R2, touching AB at Y , the circle S internally and passing through the centre of S. The point X lies on the diameter passing through the centre of S2 and ∠YXO = 30◦. If the radius of S2 is 100 then what is the radius of S1 ?

Comment: Please provide a diagram....it is very difficult to get the actual picture by just reading the statements....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the cosine law.

Let $R_2$ be the center of circle $S_2$. Let $r_2$ be the radius of $S_2$.

First of all, it is easy to obtain that the radius of $S$ is $200$ and that $XO=100, XR_2=r_2$ and $OR_2=200-r_2$. Then notice that $\angle R_2XO=120{^\circ}$.

Hence by cosine law $100^2+{r_2}^2-200r_2\cos(120{^\circ})=(200-r_2)^2$

Now solve for $r_2$ we get ${r_2}^2+100r_2+10000={r_2}^2-400r_2+40000\implies 500r_2=30000\implies r_2=60$.

Comment: After simplification, the resultant equation is not quadratic any more and the answer is 60.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I simplified wrongly, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Please provide me a figure

Comment: You should have a figure yourself right? I used all the same point system as described in your question and I have not defined any new points. Unfortunately I am not at an environment where I am able to scan a picture so you would have to use your version of the figure.

Comment: for what XR2=r2 is used?

Comment: $r_2$ is the radius of circle $R_2$

Comment: I think there is a slight confusion here. You defined $R_2$ as the center of  the circle in region $R_1$ but the name $R_2$ has been used by the question as region $R_2$

Comment: That's right. In my solution $R_2$ is the center of $S_2$ due to the misinterpreting of the sentence "centered in R2" as "centered at R2". I will put that in my answer.